# How to detect and isolate C++ Access Violation Error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, access-violation

While i was developing a C++ application,

I was using a simple `list<int> *somelist = new list<int>();`
that contains data.

I was trying to iterate this list using something like this:

```
for (list<int>::iterator j=somelist->begin();j!=somelist->end();j++)
{
    //do something with *j
}
```

When i was doing something with the pointer `j` because of a chain reaction the data that i was going to access was removed from the list and no longer exists.

So, i am being prompted with an Access Violation Error Msg.

Can someone tell me how to identify if the pointer `j` is a bad ptr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With multi-threading your iterator can become invalidated if some other thread removes elements from the list. With a low-level programming such as C++, there is no way to detect this problem once it has happened. Your best bet is to "**prevent this from happening**."

Use synchronization functions (e.g., `WaitForSingleObject` in Windows) to control access to shared STL containers.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done. You have to not delete the list during traversal.

Answer (score 1):

The bug in your code is that you need to handle this when you still know you removed it. Afterwards you cannot handle it anymore. In the following example, `dosomething` returns true when the element should be removed

```
for (list<int>::iterator j=somelist->begin();j!=somelist->end();) {
   if(dosomething(j)) {
     /* should remove it! */
     j = somelist->erase(j);
   } else {
     ++j;
   }
}
```

Comment: the situation is more like two threads. where one reads the list, and the other removes elements from a list at the same time

Comment: @Mafahir then you should ensure proper synchronisation on whatever places that are affected.

Comment: @Mafahir Fairoze - STL Containers aren't thread safe, you must remember that.